# How to ignore case sensitive in this xpath c# selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, automation

I have a simple xpath:

```
driver.findelement(by.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'chain')]").click()
```

This code is working but its not recognize ***`chain`*** in uppercase, how to ignore case sensitive in this xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use translate, but to make it shorter, you may translate only characters you are looking for

```xml
//li[contains(translate(text(), 'CHAIN', 'chain'), 'chain')]
```

If you are going to use this a lot, you may even write a method for that. I'll write in Java (sorry, not familiar with C#):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String l = "//li[" + containsTextIgnoringCase("StackOverflow") + "]";
    System.out.println(l);
}

public static String containsTextIgnoringCase(String s) {
    return String.format("contains(translate(text(), '%s', '%s'), '%s')", s.toUpperCase(), s.toLowerCase(), s);
}
```

output:

```xml
//li[contains(translate(text(), 'STACKOVERFLOW', 'stackoverflow'), 'stackoverflow')]
```

There's some space for optimization (not sure if it costs the effort, but still): translate only unique chars, and handle quotes, if passed in string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `contains` and `translate` functions together like this:

```xml
//li[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'chain')]
```

Comment: Sry it didn't worked out ,still not able to recognise

Comment: No need to translate other chars, than "chain"

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk yes I see, thanks for your reply. But in this case I want tell the user how to ignore uppercase in general without specific text.

Comment: @SrinuReddy are you sure the target is in the `li` tag? please replace the `li` with `*` character like this `//*[contains.....` or can you share relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of `chain` in the way that assign it to a separate `string` variable and then apply `.ToUpper()` extension on it.

```
string strChain = "chain";
string getUpper = strChain.ToUpper();
```

It will give you `cain` in uppercase.

You can use it directly inside `driver.findelement`.